# JUnit Test import works, but IntelliJ doesn't see it beforehand

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

When creating tests, IntelliJ doesn't seem to see JUnit by itself. However, if I manually write the import, it is recognized without a problem. Everything works fine, so it's not a big deal, but it is a strange behaviour.

When I type @Test, the autocomplete shows:

[image: Autocomplete]

After writing, and alt+enter:

[image: After alt-enter]

After manually writing the import:

[image]

Since Maven and IntelliJ work perfectly after manually writing the import, it seems a minor configuration problem. I have already deleted all *.iml files in this project, so it's probably a global configuration?

Comment: Please check Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from Import and Completion and make sure that "org.junit" or "org.junit.Test" is not in that list.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. Now shamefully wondering why I couldn't find that...